# Responsive navbar dissapears < 768px

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been struggling with a bootstrap navbar, basically what I wanna do is a simple responsive navbar.

I've looked up all kinds of tutorials and I can't seem to figure out my mistake.

Basically, my navbar dissapears when my screen width is under 768px here is the code for my navbar and also the css.

HTML:

```
<header>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-expand-md">
        <div class="container">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
            <img src="{% static 'images/logo2.png' %}" width="40%" />
          </a>
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button
              type="button"
              class="navbar-toggle"
              data-toggle="collapse"
              data-target="#navbarCollapse"
            >
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="/" class="nav-link">Acasă</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="/about/" class="nav-link">Despre</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="/services/" class="nav-link">Servicii</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="/products/" class="nav-link">Produse</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="/quote/" class="nav-link">Calculator</a>
              </li>
              {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'profile' %}"
                  >Profilul tau, {{request.user.username}}</a
                >
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a
                  href="{% url 'logout' %}"
                  class="nav-link"
                  style="color: #ebce09"
                  >Logout</a
                >
              </li>
              {% else %}
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a
                  href="{% url 'login' %}"
                  class="nav-link"
                  style="color: #ebce09"
                  >Login</a
                >
              </li>
              {% endif %}
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
```

CSS:

```
* {`enter code here`
  box-sizing: border-box !important;
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  color: #666666;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.80857;
  font-weight: normal;
}
a {
  color: #1f1f1f;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  outline: none !important;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

*,
*::after,
*::before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: #12153c;
}
.nav-link {
  color: white;
  margin-left: 40px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.nav-link:hover {
  color: #d0b608;
}
```

Also, I'm working with django so ignore the {% %} django inputs

```css
* {
  `enter code here` box-sizing: border-box !important;
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  color: #666666;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.80857;
  font-weight: normal;
}

a {
  color: #1f1f1f;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  outline: none !important;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

*,
*::after,
*::before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: #12153c;
}

.nav-link {
  color: white;
  margin-left: 40px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.nav-link:hover {
  color: #d0b608;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">

<header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-expand-md">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
        <img src="{% static 'images/logo2.png' %}" width="40%" />
      </a>
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse">
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="/" class="nav-link">Acasă</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="/about/" class="nav-link">Despre</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="/services/" class="nav-link">Servicii</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="/products/" class="nav-link">Produse</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="/quote/" class="nav-link">Calculator</a>
          </li>
          {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'profile' %}">Profilul tau, {{request.user.username}}</a
                >
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a
                  href="{% url 'logout' %}"
                  class="nav-link"
                  style="color: #ebce09"
                  >Logout</a
                >
              </li>
              {% else %}
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a
                  href="{% url 'login' %}"
                  class="nav-link"
                  style="color: #ebce09"
                  >Login</a
                >
              </li>
              {% endif %}
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
```

Comment: This is normal behavior it turns into hamburger menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cross-referenced it to their navbar documentation for bootstrap 5.  Not sure what version of bootstrap you're using but the piece that was missing to make it work was:

```
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
   <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
```

which I replaced for this:

```
<div class="navbar-header">
   <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   </button>
</div>
```

Run this code and you should see a pink square that would normally be a nav icon.

```css
* {`enter code here`
  box-sizing: border-box !important;
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  color: #666666;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.80857;
  font-weight: normal;
}
a {
  color: #1f1f1f;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  outline: none !important;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

*,
*::after,
*::before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: #12153c;
}
.nav-link {
  color: white;
  margin-left: 40px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.nav-link:hover {
  color: #d0b608;
}

button.navbar-toggler {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<header>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-expand-md">
        <div class="container">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
            <img src="{% static 'images/logo2.png' %}" width="40%" />
          </a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="/" class="nav-link">Acasă</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="/about/" class="nav-link">Despre</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="/services/" class="nav-link">Servicii</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="/products/" class="nav-link">Produse</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="/quote/" class="nav-link">Calculator</a>
              </li>
              <!--{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'profile' %}"
                  >Profilul tau, {{request.user.username}}</a
                >
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a
                  href="{% url 'logout' %}"
                  class="nav-link"
                  style="color: #ebce09"
                  >Logout</a
                >
              </li>
              {% else %}-->
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a
                  href="{% url 'login' %}"
                  class="nav-link"
                  style="color: #ebce09"
                  >Login</a
                >
              </li>
              {% endif %}
            </ul>
          </div>
          <!--<div class="navbar-header">
            <button
              type="button"
              class="navbar-toggle"
              data-toggle="collapse"
              data-target="#navbarCollapse"
            >
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
          </div>-->
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
```

Comment: Hello, it doesn't seem to do any difference. The navbar is hidden under 768px, if you need the whole code here it is: https://github.com/dngbr/Marut  . If you need anything else please tell me

Comment: The normal behaviour is that the nav will condense to a hidden nav, and the toggle will appear. What are you wanting to happen if this isn't desired?

Comment: I want it to condense into a hidden nav but the toggle does not appear. That's my problem. The toggle is nowhere. I want the brand in the left side and the toggle in right, if the nav is a div: the brand remains even in mobile, if its a nav element, the brand dissapears too

Comment: Do you see the pink square in my example per chance? The icon is missing in mine but I assume it should be in yours, but sounds like it's just missing.

Comment: I don't see the pink square in your example.

Comment: Yeah bootstrap hides the nav and replaces it with a toggle button by default for a reason. That button has an icon that should look like the exampe on this page: https://bootstrapshuffle.com/classes/navbar/navbar-toggler-icon (make screen smaller to see the nav switch to a toggle). You can see the pink box when running the code snippet above?

Comment: I do understand the behaviour of the navbar. What I didn't understand is why the toggle does not show up

Comment: Thank you for you patience, somehow I fixed it, also needed to add navbar-dark for the toggler to appear. Thank you sir!

Comment: No problem, glad you could figure it out in the end!